# Using a ternary operator to return HTML

Tags: html, reactjs, render, ternary

I know how to use a ternary operator like this:

```
{ this.state.showThanks ? 'Thanks for your response!' : null }
```

But I would like to render html and then remove that html on click

```
    { this.state.showThanks ? <input type="submit" className="decisionButtons" id="canDecisionButton" value="I can play" onClick={() => this.canPlay()}/>
                <input type="submit" className="decisionButtons" id="cantDecisionButton" value="I cannot play" onClick={() => this.cannotPlay()}/>
  : 'Thanks for your response!' }
```

I tried something like the above but am getting errors so how can I place html inside a ternary in my react render method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

JSX elements, like what your ternary expression returns when showThanks is true, always need one parent node. You have two inputs - they need a single parent, so enclose them in a div.

```
{ this.state.showThanks ? 
<div>
    <input type="submit" className="decisionButtons" id="canDecisionButton" value="I can play" onClick={() => this.canPlay()}/>
    <input type="submit" className="decisionButtons" id="cantDecisionButton" value="I cannot play" onClick={() => this.cannotPlay()}/>
</div>
  : 'Thanks for your response!' }
```

Comment: I propose exchanging the `<div>` and `</div>` in the middle section of the ternary expression for React's `<Fragment>` and `</Fragment>` respectively. You can include `Fragment` in the import of React: `import React, { Component, Fragment } from "react"`. It ensures the rendered HTML does not contain nested divs (which can sometimes lead to problems). Just thought I'd put it out there.

Comment: does this work for multiple div or a combination of div & br